# Simple Way to Switch a CSS Class in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I appreciate all the suggestions I've gotten so far-thank you!

I'll try to describe a bit better what I'm  trying to do:

I want to switch a CSS class on the active (clicked on) tab item on a  item (to make a highlight effect while its related content is showing).

The JS Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/4YX5R/9/ from Vlad Nicula comes close to what I'm trying to achieve, however I can't get it to work in my code.

The tabs are linked to content which is shown on the page when the tab is clicked. This part is working fine. I just want to change the CSS style on the ContentLink items when its content is being shown.

I'd also like to keep the content for ContentLink1 visible when the page loads, as it is now in the code, and for ContentLink1 to have the CSS .infoTabActive class when the page loads. When the ContentLink tab is not clicked, it should have the .infoTab class.

This is what I have so far:

HTML:

```
 <article class="grid-70 infoContainer">


        <a class="infoTab" id="aTab" href="javascript:show('a')">ContentLink1</a>
        <a class="infoTab" id="bTab" href="javascript:show('b')">ContentLink2</a>
        <a class="infoTab" id="cTab" href="javascript:show('c')">ContentLink3</a>

    <div id="a">
  <p> Inhalt 1111111.</p></div>     



    <div id="b">
    <p>Inhalt 222222222
    </p></div>

    <div id="c">
    <p>Inhalt 33333333
    <7p></div>  

    </article>
```

Javascript:

```
window.onload = function () {
     document.getElementById("a").style.display = "block";
}


function show(i) {

  document.getElementById('a').style.display ="none";
  document.getElementById('b').style.display ="none";
  document.getElementById('c').style.display ="none";
  document.getElementById(i).style.display ="block";

 }
```

basic CSS for tab styles I want to apply:

```
.infoTab  {
    text-decoration:none;
    color:red;
}

.infoTabActive {
    text-decoration:none;
    color:yellow;
}
```

Any pointers would be appreciated!

Comment: It doesn't work because in JSFiddle you've selected to wrap your code with `onLoad` event handler. Unselect it and it will work: http://jsfiddle.net/hSAGZ/1/.

Comment: You could use jQuery should you need more JS actions. $.addClass('') and $.removeClass('') would be more convenient ;-)

Comment: I think loading a jQuery library for a simple add/remove class is a little bit overkill

Answer (score 0):

You can switch the classes simply bu using class property on DOM element.

To replace the existing class use

```
document.getElementById("Element").className = "ClassName";
```

Similarly to add a new class to exisiting classes use

```
document.getElementById("Element").className += "ClassName";
```

Answer (score 0):

Change show function to be like this:

```
function show(i) {

  document.getElementById('a').style.display ="none";
  document.getElementById('a').className ="";
  document.getElementById('b').style.display ="none";
  document.getElementById('b').className ="";
  document.getElementById('c').style.display ="none";
  document.getElementById('c').className ="";
  document.getElementById(i).style.display ="block";
  document.getElementById(i).className ="selected";

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I [changed](http://jsfiddle.net/hSAGZ/3/) a little bit your code to make it suits your needs. 
First, change the `onload` part in the Fiddle, by `no wrap`.
Then, you need to hide each elements at start like this :

```
window.onload = function () {
     var list = document.getElementsByClassName("hide");
     for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
         list[i].style.display = "none";
     }
}
```

I added an `hide` class to achieve it. Your `show` function works well then.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like this:

add a class called `.show` which sets the element to display block.

then toggle the classname.

Here's a [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ChubbyNinja/hSAGZ/5/)

And here's an example:

**HTML**

```
<article class="grid-70 infoContainer">

    <a class="infoTab" id="aTab" href="javascript:show('a')">Werbetexte</a>
    <a class="infoTab" id="bTab" href="javascript:show('b')">Lektorate</a>
    <a class="infoTab" id="cTab" href="javascript:show('c')">Übersetzung</a>

    <div class="box" id="a">
        <div class="col1"> <p>Inhalt 1111111.</p></div>     
    </div>

    <div class="box" id="b">
        Inhalt 222222222
    </div>

    <div class="box" id="c">
        Inhalt 33333333
    </div>  

</article>
```

**JavaScript**

```
window.onload = function () {
     show('a');
}


function show(elm) {

    // get a list of all the boxes with class name box
   var shown = document.getElementsByClassName('box');

    // loop through the boxes    
    for( var i=0; i<shown.length; i++ )
    {
        // set the classname to box (removing the 'show')
         shown[i].className = 'box';   
    }

    // change the classname to box show for the element that was clicked
   document.getElementById( elm ).className = 'box show';

 }
```

**CSS**

```
.box {
    display:none;
}

.box.show {
    display:block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way I could think of is this : http://jsfiddle.net/4YX5R/9/

Basically you don't want to listen to each element. If you do that you will have issues with new tabs. If you listen to the parent element like in my example you can add new tabs without having to write any more javascript code.

```
<a class="infoTab" data-target='a' id="aTab">Werbetexte</a>
```

Each tab button has a data-target attribute that will describe the div to show as the tab content. Hiding and showing content will be done via css, not style - which is a recommended best practice -.

```
tabs.addEventListener("click", function ( ev ) {
     var childTarget = ev.originalTarget || ev.toElement;
     ...
}
```

When a tab is clicked, we check to see which element was clicked from the event listener on the parent, and then get the data-target from it. We use this as a id selector to show the new tab. We also need a reference to the old tab that was active, so we can hide it.

The logic is not that complicated, and with this you can have any number of tabs. I would recommend jQuery for this, since the event delegation might not work in all browsers with the current code.

I hope this helps :)

Comment: Thank you Vlad for your detailed explanations and the fiddle, I appreciate the advice. Your suggestion targets what I'm trying to do with the highlights on the text items, but unfortunately I couldn't get it working in my code-I probably have some other issues there. ;-)

Comment: Glad I could help. Choose my answer as best answer if you consider it right. Best of luck fixing your code :)